# Enviar imagen por correo usando SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas, quisiera que me puedan ayudar, estoy realizando un envío de correo usando SQL MAIL de SQL SERVER por la cual sí me llega el correo generado pero ahora quiero adjuntar una imagen para eso tengo una tabla que tiene un campo que almacena una imagen de formato `IMAGE`.

Cuando yo intento insertar una imagen y lo ejecuto en mi procedimiento me salta un error que es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código del *stored procedure* que genera el correo electrónico es este:

```
   alter table mail

if exists(select * from TTareasAtender where comentario='' and oficina=9)
begin

Declare @CampoSTOT7 varchar(max) 
Declare @NReg7 int 
Declare @NRegTot7 int 

IF OBJECT_ID('DBProAuxQP_QA..#temp7')  IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE DBProAuxQP_QA..#temp7
        END
        else

Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NumeroRecibo) as NN,* into #temp7 from TTareasAtender  where comentario='' and oficina=9

--select * from #temp1

Set @NReg7=0
Set @NRegTot7= (select count(*) as Cantidad from #temp7 where comentario='' and oficina=9 and NN=@NReg6)
set @CampoSTOT7='0'
WHILE @NReg7<=@NRegTot7
begin
set @NReg7= @NReg7 + 1

    Declare @cantidad7 as varchar(10),@Asunto7 as Varchar(500), @Mensaje7 as Varchar(500),@Tarea7 as varchar(500),@agencia7 as varchar(160),@img as varbinary(max) 

    Set @cantidad7=  (select count(*) as Cantidad from #temp7 where comentario='' and oficina=9 and NN=@NReg7)
        set @agencia7 =(select b.oficina as Agencia from #temp7 a inner join TTareasOficina b on a.oficina=b.idoficina where a.comentario='' and a.oficina=9  and NN=@NReg7)
            --set @FVR3=(select fechacumplimiento from #temp3 where IDEstadoTarea=3 and DiasFaltantes=3 and AgenciaID=7 and diasfaltantes is not null and NN=@NReg2)
        set @Tarea7 = (select tarea from #temp7 where comentario='' and oficina=9 and NN=@NReg7)
        set @Asunto7 =  @Tarea7
        set @img=(select filecontent from TTareasAtender where oficina=9 and registro=1)
    set @tableHTML=
                '<style type="text/css">
                    body 
                        {
                            font: 70.5% Tahoma;             
                            margin-left: 0px;
                            margin-top: 0px;
                            margin-right: 0px;
                            margin-bottom: 0px;
                        }                   
                        .TableFrm {
                            width:75%;
                            font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                            align-content:center;
                            margin: 0 auto;
                            }
                            .TableFrm th {
                                    border:1px solid #E0E0E0;
                                    background:#F5F5F5;
                                    padding:6px;
                                    font-weight:bold;
                                    text-align:left;    
                                    }
                            .TableFrm td {
                                    border:1px solid #E0E0E0;
                                    background:#FFF;
                                    padding:6px;
                                    text-align:left;
                                    }     
                        .table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
                        .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
                            background-color: #f5f5f5;
                        }                   

                </style>
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head id="Head1"><title>
                    .:  INFORME DE REGISTRO DE TAREA | FINANCIERA QAPAQ S.A  :.
                </title>
                <body >
                    <form method="post" id="form1">
                        <table class="TableFrm">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 100%" colspan="4" >..::   INFORME DE REGISTRO DE TAREA | FINANCIERA QAPAQ S.A::..</th>                               
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 30%">Tipo de Tarea: </th>
                                <td style="width: 70%" colspan="3">'+@Tarea7+'</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 30%">Estado Tarea: </th>
                                <td style="width: 70%" colspan="3">REGISTRO DE TAREAS</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 30%">Cantidad: </th>
                                <td style="width: 70%" colspan="3">'+@cantidad7+'</td>
                                </tr> 

                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 30%">Agencia: </th>
                                <td style="width: 70%" colspan="3">'+@agencia7+'</td>
                            </tr>                               
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 30%">Área Responsable de Atención: </th>
                                <td style="width: 70%" colspan="3">LOGISTICA - ADMINISTRACIÓN</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th style="width: 30%">imagen </th>
                                <img src="'+@img+'"/>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="4">Informe del Seguimiento de Tareas Por Vencer</th>
                             </tr>

                        </table></br>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td class="PiePagina"> SISTEMA DE REGISTRO Y ATENCIÓN DE TAREAS, FINANCIERA QAPAQ S.A. -   ©2017</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </body> '
                    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                    @profile_name = 'Incidencias_Qapaq',--Perfil de correo configurado.
                    --@recipients = 'labrahamzonq@qapaq.pe; fabanto@qapaq.pe ; asalazar@qapaq.pe  ', -- A quien se va enviar el correo.
                    --@copy_recipients ='DCOLLANTES@qapaq.pe',--'jnoriega@qapaq.pe; cbracamonte@qapaq.pe', --Quien lo va a atender
                    @blind_copy_recipients='pflores@qapaq.pe',
                    @body =@tableHTML,-- 'Este correo es enviado desde SQL Server 2005 con código TSQL por sqlPsyKrest Blog',--Cuerpo del correo.
                    @body_format = 'HTML',

                    @subject = 'REGISTRO TAREA QAPAQ - ESTADO: RECIBO REGISTRADO: LOGISTICA - ADMINISTRACION' --@Asunto ,--Asunto del correo.
                    --@importance = 'High' --[Low | Normal| High] Prioridad del correo.
                    END
                    end
end
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: qué versión de SQL estás usando?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De inicio, veamos lo que dice la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql):

> ¡IMPORTANTE! Los tipos de datos **ntext**, **text** e **image** se eliminarán en la versión futura de SQL Server (SQL Server 2016). Evite utilizar estos tipos de datos en nuevos trabajos de desarrollo y planee modificar las aplicaciones que los utilizan actualmente. Utilice **nvarchar(max)**, **varchar(max)** y **varbinary** (max) en su lugar.

*Eso solo como nota por si en algún futuro deseas actualizar la versión de SQL Server.*

Mientras tanto, pongo dos posibles soluciones:

## Solución 1:

La primera opción es almacenar las imágenes a una ruta física y posteriormente, incluir esa ruta en el *stored procedure* para adjuntar el archivo:

Para guardar la imagen a una ruta física:

```
DECLARE @ImageData varbinary(max);
SELECT @ImageData = (SELECT convert(varbinary(max), filecontent, 1) FROM TTareasAtender WHERE oficina=9 AND registro=1)

DECLARE @Path nvarchar(1024);
SELECT @Path = 'C:\Imagenes\RutaDondeSeGuardanLasImagenes';

DECLARE @Filename NVARCHAR(1024);
SELECT @Filename = (SELECT fileilename FROM TTareasAtender WHERE oficina=9 AND registro=1);

DECLARE @FullPathToOutputFile NVARCHAR(2048);
SELECT @FullPathToOutputFile = @Path + '\' + @Filename;

DECLARE @ObjectToken INT
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FullPathToOutputFile, 2;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close';
EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken;
```

Para enviarla por correo electrónico:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Incidencias_Qapaq',
@recipients = 'tucorreo@midominio.com',
@blind_copy_recipients = 'pflores@qapaq.pe',
@subject = 'REGISTRO TAREA QAPAQ - ESTADO: RECIBO REGISTRADO: LOGISTICA - ADMINISTRACION'
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML',
@file_attachments = @Filename-- --> Este es la ruta del archivo que se generó anteriormente
```

Referencias:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9127325/3200493
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql

## Solución 2:

Dado que tienes la imagen guardada en un tipo de dato `image`, lo primero que haremos es convertirla a `varbinary`, para que posteriormente la integremos en el cuerpo del HTML:

Declaramos la variable de tipo `VARBINARY` y le asignamos el contenido del `image`:

```
DECLARE @ImageData varbinary(max);
SELECT @ImageData = (SELECT convert(varbinary(max), filecontent, 1) FROM TTareasAtender WHERE oficina=9 AND registro=1)
```

Dentro del cuerpo HTML ponemos el *tag* `<img>` de la siguiente forma:

```
<img src="cid:' + @ImageData + '"/>
```

Comment: ¡Qué buena respuesta! mandar la imagen como adjunto, preciso. Sólo me queda la duda: hasta donde tengo entendido no se puede definir esa imagen dentro de una parte del HTML que se va a mostrar porque va como adjunto, o sí se puede?

Comment: @fresyfx justo ando buscando eso, aunque teniendo la image como varbinary creo que sí es posible, a lo mejor y tu respuesta solo necesita probada para echarla a andar directamente desde el HTML :)

Comment: eso lo hice antes, por eso la respuesta :D

Comment: Buenas tardes, por lo que tengo entendido de esta manera se enviaría la imagen dentro del correo ? o se enviaría como adjunto? porque tengo entendido que para enviar un archivo adjunto en sp_Sendmail se usa el comando :  @file_attachments , por favor a la espera de que me aclaren la pronta duda

Answer (score 0):

Me late que tu problema está en esta línea:

```
Declare 
      @cantidad as varchar(10),
      @Asunto as Varchar(100), 
      @Mensaje as Varchar(100),
      @Tarea as varchar(150),
      @agencia as varchar(250),
      @FVR1 as varchar(250), 
      @img as image
```

Reemplaza por:

```
Declare 
      @cantidad as varchar(max),
      @Asunto as Varchar(max), 
      @Mensaje as Varchar(max),
      @Tarea as varchar(max),
      @agencia as varchar(max),
      @FVR1 as varchar(max), 
      @img as varbinary(max)
```

Utiliza `varbinary(max)` en lugar de `image`:

```
@img as image
@img as varbinary(max)
```

Una variable `varbinary(max)` puede ser pasada como valor para un parámetro de imagen.

Recomendación por experiencia: cuando desarrolles envio de correos, los estilos van en inline porque no todos los clientes de correo renderizan igual, revisa: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

**Edición**

Reemplaza:

```
<img =" '+@img+'"/>
```

Por

```
<img src="'+@img+'"/>
```

Si en la variable @img tienes una ruta definida, funcionará siempre y cuando en la edición del código anterior a esta edición lo reemplaces, es decir:

```
@img as image
```

Por:

```
@img as varchar(max)
```

**Edición 2**

En caso no tengas una URL de donde se pueda visualizar la imagen te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

En un proyecto web, crea un handler o un controlador o un webmethod que al pasarle el nombre del archivo, éste lo renderize, algo así:

```
http://miwebsite.com/cms/imagen?nombre=imagen-891248a4d30ce74c120a0ebba1ba4af.png
```

Con esto funcionando, en el script usa:

```
<img src="http://miwebsite.com/cms/imagen?nombre='+@img+'"/>
```

y comprobando que al visitar el enlace se muestre la imagen, funcionará y se visualizará en el correo enviado :D

Comment: Gracias por comentar tu respuesta ahora el problema cuando ejecuto mi procedimiento me sale este error :

Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_AlertaRegistroTarea_Lima, Line 785
The data types varchar and varbinary(max) are incompatible in the add operator.

que me señala en este parte del error 

<img src="'+@img+'"/>

Comment: mi tabla tiene esos campo subi una imagen en forma de bits la imagen

Comment: aqui amigo :
Declare cantidad7 as varchar(10),@Asunto7 as Varchar(500), @Mensaje7 as Varchar(500),@Tarea7 as varchar(500),@agencia7 as varchar(160),@img as varbinary(max)

Comment: acabo de editar mi pregunta y ahi esta tal como me dijiste amigo

Comment: esque sin la imagen si me sale .

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57023/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-pierro).